# How to compute mean, cv and standard deviation simultaneously using by group in R

Tags: r

I want to compute mean, cv and standard deviation on more than 1 variable ,simultaneously, and then group the output (using `by` statement). Below is a snapshot of my data.

```
CLT             SOURCE          LD     BRX  

  Bt02Sm86(Lg)  GH801-2@ S7        1.5   8.6 
  Bt02Sm86(Lg)  GH801-2@ S7        1.3   8.9  
  Bt02Sm86(Lg)  GH801-2@ S7        1.8   8.7  
  Bt14Lg 26x36  GH811x810F1        1.4   9.6
  Bt14Lg 26x36  GH811x810F1        1.6  10.2   
  Bt03Sm86(Lg)  GH802-1@ S7        1.3   9.9
  Bt03Sm86(Lg)  GH802-1@ S7        1.2   8.9
  Bt03Sm86(Lg)  GH802-1@ S7        1.3   9.3   
  Bt18Lg 15x36  GH818x819F1        1.3   9.7 
  Bt18Lg 15x36  GH818x819F1        1.1   8.5 
  Bt18Lg 15x36  GH818x819F1        1.6   9.3   
  Bt19Lg 15x39  GH820x821F1        1.3   9.1
  Bt19Lg 15x39  GH820x821F1        1.5   9.3
```

I want my output to look like in following way

```
 CLT            SOURCE          mean_LD  cv_LD  std_LD  mean_BRX  cv_ld std_brx

Bt02Sm86(Lg)    GH801-2@ S7      xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx   xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx
Bt14Lg 26x36  GH811x810F1        xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx   xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx
Bt03Sm86(Lg)  GH802-1@ S7        xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx   xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx
Bt18Lg 15x36  GH818x819F1        xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx   xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx 
Bt19Lg 15x39  GH820x821F1        xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx   xx.xx    xx.xx  xx.xx
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: You can try `dplyr`, i.e. `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(CLT, SOURCE) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean,  sd))`

Comment: In base R the `aggregate` function lets you apply the same function to multiple columns using a grouping vector or vectors.

Comment: @BondedDust Yes, but it is also slow for big datasets.  Also, the results column will be matrix that may need conversion to data.frame by `do.call(data.frame, ..` (though not necessary).  Please check the benchmarks here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28909372/operation-on-multiple-column-in-a-data-frame-based-on-group-by/28911173#28911173

Comment: Thanks for the comparison. (That's not even a big dataset, but I suppose it might get even worse with 10e7 by 30 columns.)

Comment: @BondedDust Yes, it will be worse...

Comment: Thanks for the explaination @ BondedDust and Akrun.

Comment: Would you please let me know how to change denormalized data into normalized data and vice-versa. I am getting flat ouput and I need to stack or have column for each statistics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
cv <- function(x) 100*( sd(x)/mean(x))
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
     group_by(CLT, SOURCE) %>% 
     summarise_each(funs(mean, sd, cv))
```