# Using for loop to perform actions separately for different categories in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, dataframe

What is the best way to calculate values such as mean and standard deviation for each column in a data frame?
For example, if I have a data frame:

```
s <- data.frame(
  sample = c("s_1", "s_2", "s_3", "s_4", "s_5", "s_6", "s_7", "s_8"),
  flavor = c("original", "chicken", "original", "original", "cheese", "chicken", "cheese", "original"),
age = c(23, 25, 11, 5, 6, 44, 50, 2),
  scale = c( 4, 3, 2, 5, 4, 3, 1, 5))
```

How do I use the `for` loop to find the mean and `sd` values of only one of the columns (for example, `age`) based on another column (for example, `flavor`)

I've got the code for finding the mean and standard deviations individually but was wondering if there was a way to use loops instead.

```
print(paste("mean =",
              mean(s[s$flavor == "original", "age"]), 
              "sd =",
              sd(s[s$flavor == "original", "age"])))
```

Comment: So I don't have to write three codes that vary slightly, for each of the categories (flavor).

Comment: Try using dplyr instead: `library(dplyr)`, then `s %>% group_by(flavor) %>% summarize(mean = mean(age), sd = sd(age))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compute mean, cv and standard deviation simultaneously using by group in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28916810/how-to-compute-mean-cv-and-standard-deviation-simultaneously-using-by-group-in)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a `for` loop, then loop through the `unique` elements of 'flavor', subset the 'age' based on the the values of 'flavor' and get the `mean` and sd` for each category to be included in a vector 'v1'

```
v1 <- c()
for(un1 in unique(s$flavor)){
  tmp <- s$age[s$flavor == un1]
  v1 <- c(v1, paste("mean =", mean(tmp), "sd =", sd(tmp)))
}

v1
#[1] "mean = 10.25 sd = 9.28708781050335" "mean = 34.5 sd = 13.4350288425444" 
#[3] "mean = 28 sd = 31.1126983722081"
```

Instead of creating a NULL vector initially (`v1 <- c()`), we can also pre-allocate a vector of length equal to the length of unique elements in 'flavor' (should be more efficient than the above)

```
 v1 <- numeric(length(unique(s$flavor)))
```

Inside the loop change the 'v1 <-' to

```
nm1 <- unique(s$flavor)
for(i in seq_along(unique(s$flavor))){
    tmp <- s$age[s$flavor == nm1[i] ]
    v1[i] <-paste("mean =", mean(tmp), "sd =", sd(tmp))
  }
```

---

But this can be done as a group by operation with `base R`

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(age~flavor, s, FUN = function(x) c(Mean = mean(x), SD= sd(x))))
```

Or a more efficient approach with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(s)[, paste("mean =", mean(age), "sd =", sd(age)), flavor]$V1
```

Answer (score 0):

Since loops are not efficient, you may use dplyr like Patronus suggested OR use plyr as follows:

```
require(plyr)
s.summary <- ddply(s, c("flavor"), summarise, 
    N= length(age), 
    mean= round(mean(age),2),
    sd= round(sd(age),2),
    se = round(sd/sqrt(N),2)
)
s.summary
```